# git: can I issue commands from two computers mounted to same file system

Tags: linux, windows, git

I hope I can explain this in a simple way ...

The files I am adding to git is on a Linux server. I access these files from various computers, depending on where I am. Sometimes it is with a Windows machine, with a drive mapped to a network drive. Sometimes I ssh into the server.

I created my git repository while working on the Windows machine with a network drive mapped to the appropriate file system, lets call it W:. I was in W:\ when I created the repository.

When I ssh into the server the directory would be something like: \home\mydir\WORKING_DIR\

Can I now, while in my ssh session, issue git commands to update the repository on the Linux macine?

---

This is not an answer, but it is too long for the comments.

I'm getting to the end of my tether with git. It has now completely messed up everything. Trying to google for a solution is really fruitless. Nothing is specific enough and then when you do try something that might be relevant it just totally screws things up further.

I tried changing the path in the config file manually. But I really didn't know what to change it to. If it should be relative, then relative to what?

I tried a couple of things and ended up with /home/myname/myworkingdir/

However, now it deleted my files again and set me back to some unknown state. Fortunately I backed my files up beforehand. So I tried to copy them back into place and add them again. I get "fatal: 'myfilename and path in here' is beyond a symbolic link. I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

git status just shows more things to be deleted.

Comment: I think I have just answered my own question and the answer is no. I did a "git status" on the Linux machine and got an error: "fatal: Could not switch to '.git/W:': No such file or directory". So obviously git takes the Windows drive into account ... bummer

Comment: I am not sure, but this could be a permission issue. Because IIRC git only stores relative paths (that's the reason you can move a repository without any special tools). So the error you get confuses me a bit.

Comment: I had a look at the config file in git and it has:
worktree=W:/
That is pretty Windows specific. I don't know whether that can be changed.

Comment: Have you created a worktree with `git worktree add`? In which file is this `worktree=W:/` located? I can not find any absolute paths in my `.git/` folders

Comment: It is in the config file in .git

Comment: In general, and with a *normal* repository, Git should not have any issues with accessing it from multiple machines mounted at different paths, even concurrently. Assuming Git versions are compatible, there shouldn’t be a practical difference to using it from multiple machines vs. using it in multiple terminals on a single machine. – So the answer to your question would be: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: @jss Could you tell me what block this line belongs to? In none of my `.git/config` files have I found an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

There are probably situations where this works without any issue (e.g. `git status`) and others where `git` assumes exclusive access (e.g. attempting to commit the same change simultaneously from two computers which both have access to the same working directory).

Wanting to ask this seems like a symptom of misunderstanding the Git model, anyway. You'll be much better off with a separate working directory on each computer (or even multiple check-outs on the same computer). Git was designed for distributed, detached operation - go with that, and you'll be fine.

Comment: It is not a misunderstanding of Git. It was an attempt to fix a situation that presented itself because of a decision that I made to create the repository from my workstation rather than on the cluster itself. When I realised that committing from the workstation was presenting me with other problems I decided to move to committing from the cluster itself. This is still what I want to do.

Comment: Creating a new independent check-out would still be my recommended course of action. You can copy over the changed files into that if you have uncommitted changes in a hosed working copy, regardless of how exactly it is hosed.